# How to do Fixed width with fixed child div?

Tags: html, css

http://themorpheustech.com/test/test1.php

Please go to the Link.

The menu is Fixed Position, when you scroll down it will display, this is what exactly I want.

And you can see there is lot of menu and the Fixed menuWrapper having 100% width and the div inside the Wrapper having fixed width(1240px) because it has 19 menus.

Okay the problem is when I see the website in low resolution monitor: 1024px monitors, for testing just resize the browser window. Everything working fine, I mean the fixed main menu. But the problem is its shows up to Menu 18, and there is a Horizontal Scroll bar, bottom of the  browser window, if I scroll it the content of the websites shows everything but the menu? see it's shows up to Menu 18.

I need the solution for this either in CSS or Jquery.

The code I used:

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#menuWrapper {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    background-color:#999;
}
#menu {
    position:relative;
    width:1240px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:80px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#content {
    padding-top:90px;
    width:1240px;
    background-color:#F3F3F3;
    margin:0 auto;
}
</style>

<div id="menuWrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        Menu 1 | 
        Menu 2 | 
        Menu 3 | 
        Menu 4 | 
        Menu 5 | 
        Menu 6 | 
        Menu 7 | 
        Menu 8 | 
        Menu 9 | 
        Menu 10 | 
        Menu 11 | 
        Menu 12 | 
        Menu 13 | 
        Menu 14 | 
        Menu 15 | 
        Menu 16 | 
        Menu 17 | 
        Menu 18 | 
        Menu 19 
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    Website Content<br />
    Website Content<br />
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Comment: what??????????? Edit: ohhh pheeew I got it wait

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, you didn't understood what i am saying?

Comment: OOPS sorry, See i need fixedDivWithFullWidth should be fixed position, its works well. But when low resolution monitors the content inside childDivWithFixedWidth Div is not showing like "content" Div when we scroll the horizontal scroll bar. See the Screenshot.

Comment: did you even read my answer? I already gave you the solution

Comment: @Mr.Alien, Hi Brother, i just Modify my question with Live website URL. Please help me.

Comment: Also, why do you assume that everyone's browser window is going to be as wide as their monitor?

Answer (score 1):

The fixed width seems to be doing exactly what it's intended to do:  Display the same width no matter what the screen resolution.  If you want to show a different width, consider CSS3 media queries http://cssmediaqueries.com/.  If the problem you are having is, instead, with the content in the box scrolling, you can set it otherwise like this:

```
#content { overflow: auto; }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the Reply, but  i hope my question is quite not clear, so now i attached the screenshot. Please have a look on my question.

Comment: @rkaartikeyan, your demo screen makes no difference to any of these answers. You are trying to fit a size 20 shoe into a size 12 shoe-box... there is no CSS in the world that can solve your problem. Something is sticking out or getting chopped off no matter what. The real solution is to make your site a more common width.... reduce the number of menu items to something more reasonable or wrap your menu to another row.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that #menu is wider than the browser window, which gives you the horizontal scroll bar. Using `overflow: auto` or `overflow:hidden` is not optimal because the first results in a horizontal scrollbar and the second will hide menu items from the user.

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xHrGq) that does the following:

1. Browser windows (viewports) smaller than 1240px (or without media query support) get a version of the menu that allows the menu items to wrap, without the horizontal scroll bars (I replaced "width: 1240px" with "min-width: 1240px"
2. Viewports larger than 1240px (with media query support) get the full fixed menu width treatment.

The media queries may have to be adjusted at different widths, but the general concept should stay the same.

You can use [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to get media query support in older browsers.

I hope that is helpful.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just what you stated above. The 'Fixed width' is 1240 px and the screen size is 1024 px. It's impossible to display a div that is 1240 px on a screen that is less than 1240 px without the div overflowing, either into other content or via a scroll bar depending on your overflow settings. You could try one of two things. Removing the height of the #menu div and specifying a width as you have done will cause the content to wrap and be displayed on a new line. Alternatively, specifying a width and a height will cause the content to overflow and a scroll bar to be added. To ensure this behavior occurs across browsers you can add:

```
#menu { overflow: auto; }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ...or reduce the menu to a more reasonable number of items.

Comment: Then there's that approach. That also works and makes for easier navigation.